# Codeigniter - Change the URL Path of my Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently my URL is domain.de/site/home, domain.de/site/about.

But i want that my URL ist domain.de/home, domain.de/about etc.

I already have a really simple Controller. In this Controller i`ve a function for each Site:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->home();
}

public function home() {
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_home");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

public function about() {
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_about");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}
}
```

Comment: Controller Home and Controller About, each with public function index() to serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `application/config/route.php` and add following route path

```
$route['home'] = "site/home";
$route['about'] = "site/about";
```

Comment: Thanks that`s working !
Unfournetly i cant give you a vote up because reputation ..

Answer (score -1):

You can define the association between a URL pattern and a controller/action in your config/routes.php file. Read the [docs here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) and you will understand how it can be done.

By default, your routes will be {domain}/{controller_name}/{action_name} unless you override that in routes.php where you can assign to your controller/action a different URL pattern.

So probably in your case you would need something along the lines of:

```
$route['home'] = 'site/index';
$route['about'] = 'site/about';
```

Even better you might want to set your site controller as default controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

Then all requests starting from the base url will get directed to actions in your site controller. That is {domain}/{action_name} will be directed to site/action_name automatically.

Comment: Thanks that`s working !
Unfournetly i cant give you a vote up because reputation ..

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this please explain why?